# Is there any problem in using "/"as character in fortran?

Tags: fortran, character, gfortran

Below is a small code for building a calculator type toy model for doing arithmetics with two numbers.

```
    character::x
    real::a,b,c

    write(*,*) "enter first number"
    read(*,*) a
    write(*,*) "enter second number"
    read(*,*) b



    write(*,*) "+ for addition"
    write(*,*) "- for subtraction"
    write(*,*) "* for multiplication"
    write(*,*) "/ for division"

    read(*,*) x

    if(x=='+') then
    write(*,*) a,x,b,"=",a+b

    elseif(x=='-') then
    write(*,*) a,x,b,"=",a-b


    elseif(x=='*') then
    write(*,*) a,x,b,"=",a*b


    elseif(x=="/") then
    write(*,*) a,x,b,"=",a/b

    else
    write(*,*) "error"

    end if
    end
```

When I am trying to divide, i.e, using "/" as x, the output is showing as "error",as in the last if statement. But if I replace / with d in the code, the output is coming as it should come. Is there any restriction on using / as character? I am using gfortran as compiler.

**The code below, replacing / with d works just fine.

```
character::x
real::a,b,c

write(*,*) "enter first number"
read(*,*) a
write(*,*) "enter second number"
read(*,*) b



write(*,*) "+ for addition"
write(*,*) "- for subtraction"
write(*,*) "* for multiplication"
write(*,*) "d for division"

read(*,*) x

if(x=='+') then
write(*,*) a,x,b,"=",a+b

elseif(x=='-') then
write(*,*) a,x,b,"=",a-b


elseif(x=='*') then
write(*,*) a,x,b,"=",a*b


elseif(x=="d") then
write(*,*) a,x,b,"=",a/b

else
write(*,*) "error"

end if
end
```